# My App not working on Marshmallow but works on Nougat?

Tags: android

I m new to Android development. I have developed an app using the android studio. The problem is that after generating the signed APK, when I m trying to install the app on an android device with MARSHMALLOW on it, it's not getting installed showing error message "APP CANNOT BE INSTALLED" message, but it gets installed on an android device with NOUGAT on it instead I have set minSDKVersion to 19.

Here's my manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.adityakumarsingh.arduinobot"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SpalshTheme">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Accelerometer"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BluetoothConnection"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GameMode"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Voicerecog"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here's my build file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.adityakumarsingh.arduinobot"
      minSdkVersion 19
      targetSdkVersion 26
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
               }

    }

 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     mavenLocal()
               }

  dependencies {
          implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
          implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
          implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-
          layout:1.0.2'
          compile 'io.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:1.8.0'
          compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
          compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
          implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
            }
```

What to do? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Are you able to install any other APK? If no, please take a look at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37190/application-cannot-be-installed-in-the-default-install-location

Comment: Which signature are you using to sign it? And if you already have it installed, it'll only get installed of the version number is higher than the installed one so do uninstall any same version installs.

Comment: any other apk means?

Comment: In my case I got this message 'APP CANNOT BE INSTALLED' because my phone storage was full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it mostly is the signature Which is causing issues. Try having a v2 plus v1 signature while signing the apk instead of just any one. I've seen this error when i was just using the v2 method. Adding the v1 signature will help.

V2 signatures sign the module and work for nougat and more. It'll not work on older versions of android so you'll have to use the v1 for full apk signature as well. This will let older versions install it with verification using v1 and nougat and above should still use v2. Use both. Details on this can be found at their site:

https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2

Also make sure that there isn't any already installed apk with the same version number as the one you are trying to install. It'll fail if it's already installed and the version number is the same.

Comment: Ohkay that sorted out the installation problem. But now when trying to open the app on marshmallow running device it shows "Unfortunately <app name> has stopped" but still works fine on Nougat platform. :(

Comment: Check the logs in logcat, post the exception that happens, put your package name in the search box to see it... Post the logs and start another question

Comment: @Kushan I've this same issue, my app is working on every android version except 6.0.1

Comment: @KaranKhurana write a post with the exact issue faced so that i can help :)